# Foreach IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I tried already some Solutions from here.. without success!

This is my **code** and the **error** message below,

```
SQLite.SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath);

            using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath)) 
                {

                    int i = 0;
                    var d = from x in db.Table<stations>() select x; 
                    foreach (var sd in d) 
                    {
                        pushpin[] Tanke = new pushpin[i];
                        Tanke[i].Titel = sd.name.ToString(); //IndexOutOfRangeException (see below)
                        Tanke[i].Text = sd.brand.ToString();
                        Tanke[i].longitude = sd.longitude;
                        Tanke[i].latitude = sd.latitude;

                        MapLayer.SetPosition(Tanke[i], new Location(Tanke[i].latitude, Tanke[i].longitude));
                        pinLayer.Children.Add(Tanke[i]);
                        ToolTipService.SetToolTip(Tanke[i], Tanke[i].Titel);

                        i++;
                    } 
                    db.Dispose();
                    db.Close();
                }
```

[image]

Comment: why do you want to declare array inside for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how you are creating your array of `pushpin`. It doesn't look like you need the array so do this instead:

SQLite.SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath);

```
using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath)) 
    {
        var d = from x in db.Table<stations>() select x; 
        foreach (var sd in d) 
        {
            var tmp = new pushpin();
            tmp.Titel = sd.name.ToString(); //IndexOutOfRangeException (see below)
            tmp.Text = sd.brand.ToString();
            tmp.longitude = sd.longitude;
            tmp.latitude = sd.latitude;

            MapLayer.SetPosition(tmp, new Location(tmp.latitude, tmp.longitude));
            pinLayer.Children.Add(tmp);
            ToolTipService.SetToolTip(tmp, tmp.Titel);
        } 
        db.Dispose();
        db.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are creating an array of zero elements when i is zero.

```
pushpin[] Tanke = new pushpin[i];
Tanke[i].Titel = sd.name.ToString();
```

Then you access the first element using [0]. That won't work. There is no element in a zero element array.

Answer (score 0):

While you are stepping over entries in a foreach and create each time a Array of zero elements ( i = 0 ) you can't save something becauste the [0] element is not existing